# ProjectName.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I'm getting the following error when I try and run a web site in production via its URL:

> ProjectName.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'.
>   Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section
>   of the application config file.

My web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjectNameEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProjectNameModel.csdl|res://*/ProjectNameModel.ssdl|res://*/ProjectNameModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SomeServer;initial catalog=SomeDB;User Id=SomeID;Password=SomePassWord;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I don't have an entityFramework section in my config file (as per the error) but the project runs fine from Visual Studio in the production environment.

To clarify - via the URL I get an error, via Visual Studio it works fine.

Comment: Did you manage to find what the problem was ?